# How to understand condition IE comments?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working with a theme and I found conditional comments to add classes to the html tag depending on version of Internet Explorer.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

The first three are pretty straightforward. I'm having trouble understanding the 4th one.

What exactly does it do ?
How does it work on non-IE browsers ?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: @RichieAHB thanks for the link. But it doesn't explain what the comment after `[if gt IE 8]>` and in between `<![endif]` does. Could you help me with that please.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the 4th `html` tag isn't commented and has the condition `gt IE 8`, so just IE>8 and other browsers will read.
Older IE versions will read only the proper `html` tag for them and ignore the last because it is made for `IE>8`.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas. How does the comment after `[if gt IE 8]>` and in between `<![endif]` help in doing so?